# Converting unix time to datetime with PySpark

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I've got PySpark dataframe with column "date" which represents unix time in float type (like this 1.63144269E9). When I convert this time to *"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"* datetime format, PySpark gives me incorrect values.

For instance, converting unix time *1631442679.384516* to datetime PySpark gives *"2021-09-12 12:31:28.000"*. The number of hours, seconds and milliseconds are wrong.

I've tried different PySpark finctions they didn't gave correct values.

For example:

```
j = df.withColumn('epoch', f.from_unixtime(f.col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
j.select("epoch").show(5, False)
```

```
+-----------------------+
|epoch                  |
+-----------------------+
|2021-09-12 12:31:28.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:28.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:28.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:28.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:28.000|
+-----------------------+
```

When I create dataframe with scheme where "date" is StringType, the results is shown below.

```
+-----------------------+
|epoch                  |
+-----------------------+
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.000|
|2021-09-12 12:31:20.000|
+-----------------------+
```

Now seconds are right but hours and milliseconds are still wrong.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1.0**

I switched FloatType to DecimalType in scheme of dataframe and used the next code:

```
j = df.withColumn('epoch', f.col('date').cast("timestamp"))
j.select("epoch").show(5, False)
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+
|epoch                  |
+-----------------------+
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.385|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.435|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.547|
|2021-09-12 12:31:19.571|
|2021-09-12 12:31:20.012|
+-----------------------+
```

The hour number is still wrong. I can try to use `from_utc_timestamp(j.epoch, "GMT-3")` and time will be correct but this functions are too long in performance. I guess  `df.withColumn('epoch', f.col('date').cast("timestamp"))` use timezone from my PC but I don't know how to fix it in better way.

**UPDATE 2.0**

I used a simple decision to subtract two hours and it works fine.

```
j = df.withColumn('epoch', (f.col('date')- 7200).cast("timestamp"))
j.select("epoch").show(5, False)
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------+
|epoch                  |
+-----------------------+
|2021-09-12 10:31:19.385|
|2021-09-12 10:31:19.435|
|2021-09-12 10:31:19.547|
|2021-09-12 10:31:19.571|
|2021-09-12 10:31:20.012|
+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`from_unixtime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_unixtime.html) and [default configurations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/configuration.html), the default value of `spark.sql.session.timeZone` is Spark local time, that's why you see some hours different here. The correct way to handle it is changing Spark timezone as your expectation.

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/Los_Angeles")
```